# Unhandled SecurityException trying to Start example web service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, securityexception

I built the very simple Windows service and installer outlined in this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

It seems to have built and installed fine, but when I try to start the service I get an unhandled security exception, which states "{"The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security."}"  on the following snippet in the Sub New() subroutine:

```
If Not EventLog.SourceExists("MySource") Then
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog")
End If
```

Per some articles I've found, I've added read permissions for NETWORK SERVICE account to the Security branch and parent EventLog branch in the registry, but I still get the same error.  Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Create a new key and string value like this;

```
Key= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\<Your app name>\
String EventMessageFile value=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll
```